# Sorting and making "genes" in output bitstrings from a genetic algorithm

Tags: dataset, genetic-algorithm, similarity, bit, large-data-volumes

I was wondering if anybody had suggestions as to how I could analyze an output bitstring that is being permuted by a genetic algorithm. In particular it would be nice if I could try to identify patterns of bits  (I'm calling them genes here) that seem to yield a desirable cv score. The difficulty comes in trying to examine these datasets because there are a lot of them (I have probably already something like 30 million bitstrings that are 140 bits long and I'll probably hit over 100 million pretty quickly), so after I sort out the desirable data there is still ALOT of potential datasets and doing similarity comparisons by eye is out of the question. My questions are:

How should I compare for similarity between these bitstrings?

How can I identify "genes" in these bitstrings in an algorithmic (aka programmable) way?

Comment: Do you have a fitness function?

Comment: Yes (thats what I meant by cv but maybe thats not a commonly used term), but it something of a blackbox (I can figure out what exactly is happening with the function but itll take some time). After I've had a lot of parallel runs I wanted to take the well performing outputs and analyze those for common genes

Comment: Maybe you can supply some more information about your genes or data structure or the fitness function. Otherwise all ideas are speculative matter.

Comment: I provided an answer below, but with more information it could be completed.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to extract common gene-patterns, what about looking at the intersection of the two strings. So if you have

```
set1 =          11011101110011...
set2 =          11001100000110...
# apply bitwise '=='
set1 && set2 == 11101110000010...
```

The result now shows what genes are the same, and could be used in further analysis.

Comment: I know probably the OP is not coming back, but this answer does not make sense...

Comment: @rll Ah, I totally agree. I changed the bitwise operator, which should now be correct.

Comment: Still does not make sense. Why don't you post a working example of what you mean instead of pseudo-code? I would like to see that

Answer (score 0):

For the similarity part you need to do an exclusive-or ([XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)). The result of this bit-wise operation will give you the difference between two bit strings, and is probably the most efficient and easy way of doing it (for pair comparison). As an example:

```
>>> from bitarray import bitarray
>>> a = bitarray('0001100111')
>>> b = bitarray('0100110110')
>>> a ^ b
bitarray('0101010001')
```

Then you can either count the differences, inspect quickly where the differences lie, etc.

For the second part, it depends on the representation of course, and on the programming language (PL) chosen for the implementation. Most PL libraries will have a search function, that retrieves all or at least the first of the indexes where some pattern is found in a string (or bitstring, or bitstream...). You just have to refer to the documentation of your chosen PL to know more about the performance if you have more than one option for the task.